# Grails: writing HQL query when domains are not directly matched

Tags: grails, hql

I have a domain class named Logging which stores an id of another domain class: Organization
The structure of both domains is provided:

```
class Logging {
   Date dateCreated
   long user_id
   long organization_id
   String memberCode

   static constraints = {
      user_id(nullable: false)
      organization_id(nullable: false)
      memberCode(nullable: true)
   }
}

class Organization {
   Type type
   String name
   String memberCode
   User manager
   String collateralAutoEmails
   boolean isBlocked = true

   static constraints = {
      name(blank: false, unique: true)
      manager(nullable: true)
      memberCode(nullable: true)
      collateralAutoEmails(nullable: true)
   }

   static mapping = {
      manager(lazy: false)
   }
}
```

User enters several parameters: dateCreated, the memberCode and the name of the organization. I need to select all  elements from the Logging domain  matching these criterias.
The tricky part for me is writing the query for the name of the organisation parameter.
According to the search rules I should check whether organization.name field contains data entered by user as a substring(case insensetive) and select the corresponding element from the Logging domain.
The two domains are not mapped directly and I can't join those tables.I have tried different approaches but still haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
Logging.executeQuery("Select l from Logging l, Organization o where l.organization_id = o.id and o.dateCreated = :dateCreated and o.memberCode = :memberCode and o.name = :name", [dateCreated: dateCreated, memberCode: memberCode, name: name])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Organization.executeQuery("select o from Organization o, Logging l where o.name like = :orgName AND o.id=l.organization_id", [orgName : orgName ])
```

I didn't tried it, if it works then more search options can be added on the query, and also % can be added on the parameter, in order to enhance the search.

Comment: I am writing a realisation of a search filter for the table in gsp so I should return to the view a list consisting of Logging domain elements.Therefore I should create one long string of a hql query and execute it on a Logging domain.I am not sure that your suggestion is applicable to this situation...The guy who gave me this task told me that some equivalent of join operation had to be used